# how to remove [ , ] and single quote in class list in python 3 in single line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace, split

i have a list input and i want the O/p ( with single line of code)i have tried the below code but i am not getting the desired output.in this i want to remove `[,]` and single quote, here `bid_data` type is `<class 'list'>`
**input** `['Quantity Required', ' 1']`  
**O/p**    `1` 
  
code i have tried

```
   def scrap_bid_data():
    page_no = 1
    while page_no < 2:
        print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data...')
        url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page_no)
        print('URL created: ' + url)
        scraped_data = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml')
        extracted_data = soup_data.find('div', {'id': 'pagi_content'})
        if len(extracted_data) == 0:
            break
        else:
            for idx in range(len(extracted_data)):
                if (idx % 2 == 1):
                    bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')

                    bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
                    items = bid_data[5].split(":")[-1]
                    qnty = int(bid_data[6][1].strip())
                    dept = (bid_data[10] + bid_data[12].strip()).split(":")[-1]
                    edate = bid_data[17].split("End Date:")[-1]
                    f.writerow([bidno, items, qnty.split(":"), dept, edate])

            page_no=page_no+1
scrap_bid_data()

['BID NO: GEM/2020/B/756203', 'View Corrigendum', '', '', '', 'Item(s): Desktop Computers', 'Quantity Required: 35', '', '', '', 'Department Name And Address:', '', ' Ministry Of Electronics And Information Technology Na Hq, New Delhi Unique Identification Authority Of India (uidai) ', '', '', '', 'Start Date: 19-08-2020 05:33 PM', 'End Date: 10-09-2020 04:00 PM']
```

but by this i am getting `['1']`

 need help new to python coding.

Comment: What, **exactly** is your input? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ['Quantity Required', ' 1']

Comment: What do you mean you have a string input? `['Quantity Required', ' 1']` is a list. Do you mean that your input is a **Stringified** list? then why are you splitting at `":"` where do you actually see that? Please be more clear

Comment: `['Quantity Required', ' 1']` is this a `list` or `str`? In any case, `x=str.split(":")[1]` does not produce `['1']`. As suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga, provide a **reproducible** example (=if anybody copy-paste and run the code, one reproduce your problem)

Comment: @SMG that is not a string, that is a list, in which case, `str.split(":")` would throw a `TypeError`, not give you the output `['1']` when you `print(x)`. Again **please provide a [mcve]**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga editd the code !!

Comment: @JanStránský done need help !!

Comment: You *still* haven't provided a [mcve]. Please write a *complete piece of code* that we can copy and paste and reproduce your output.

Comment: **So** you have a list and you are trying **TO GET AN ITEM AT A SPECIFIC INDEX**? Why don't you use `['Quantity Required', ' 1'][-1]` to get the last item that you want

Comment: @SMG reproducible example = one copy-paste your code, run it and reproduce your problem. If your problem is `NameError: name 'bid_data' is not defined` than this would be OK, but according to the description, the problem is different

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga done !!

Comment: That is still not a [mcve]. **Please actually read that link and follow the instructions**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your update on what `bid_data` contains:**

Do:

```
int(bid_data[6].split(':')[1].strip()) # returns an integer
```

Explanation:

The Python string method `strip()` removes excess whitespace from both ends of a string (without arguments)

**Original below:**

Below is based on using the input you gave, `['Quantity Required', ' 1']`, to get the output of 1

If the input is `['Quantity Required', ' 1']` as a list:

```
>>> my_input = ['Quantity Required', ' 1']
>>> int(my_input[1].strip())
>>> 1 # is an integer
```

Where you can replace `my_input` with the literal list.

If the input is a string:

```
>>> string = "['Quantity Required', ' 1']"
>>> int(string.split(', ')[1].strip("'] "))
>>> 1 # is an integer
```

Comment: Good answer for a bad question.

Comment: ['BID NO: GEM/2020/B/756203', 'View Corrigendum', '', '', '', 'Item(s): Desktop Computers', 'Quantity Required: 35', '', '', '', 'Department Name And Address:', '', ' Ministry Of Electronics And Information Technology Na Hq, New Delhi Unique Identification Authority Of India (uidai) ', '', '', '', 'Start Date: 19-08-2020 05:33 PM', 'End Date: 10-09-2020 04:00 PM']

Comment: bid_data contains

Comment: qnty = int(bid_data[6][1].strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'u' error

Comment: Updated answer based on that

Comment: @LeonisSupreme  qnty = int(bid_data[6].split(', ')[1].strip("'] "))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: bid_data Type is <class,'list'>

Comment: Please learn how to debug. You can use "poor mans debugging" with `print` here. The error message is clear: the list index doesn't exist. This could be `[6]` or `[1]`. So use `print(bid_data)` to see if the list contains at least seven elements. If yes then check the next index. Does `print(bid_data[6].split(', '))` give you at least two elements?